# Can't locate object method "now" via package "Datetime"

Tags: perl, datetime

I am getting the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "now" via package "Datetime" (perhaps you forgot to load "Datetime"?) at ../scripts/dateTimeTest.pl line 4.
```

For this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

require DateTime;
my $dt = Datetime->now;
```

However, the following command-line program works:

```
perl -e 'require DateTime; my $dt = DateTime->now'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl is case-sensitive.  Change:

```
my $dt = Datetime->now;
```

to:

```
my $dt = DateTime->now;
```

You got the case right in your one-liner, but not in your script.